# Beautifulsoup retrieve 2nd table

Tags: python, list, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/103093/furia-vs-chaos"
headers= {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
stat_table = soup.find_all("table", class_="stats-table")
stat_table = stat_table[0]



for team in stat_table.find_all('tbody'):
    rows = team.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        pl_team = row.find('td', class_ = 'st-player').text
        kills = row.find('td', class_ = 'st-kills').text.replace('(', '').replace(')','')
        print(pl_team, kills)
```

There are two tables on that page but I have only managed to retrieve the first table in which I only want the players and the kills. How can I get the 2nd table also how can I add the teams name?

Comment: `stat_table = stat_table[0]` in this line you're limiting yourself to the first table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right full code would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ="https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/103093/furia-vs-chaos"
headers= {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)"}

response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
stat_table = soup.find_all("table", class_="stats-table")


for table in stat_table:
    head_row = table.find('thead').find('tr')
    this_team = head_row.find('th', class_ = 'st-teamname').text

    for team in table.find_all('tbody'):
        rows = team.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            pl_team = row.find('td', class_ = 'st-player').text
            kills = row.find('td', class_ = 'st-kills').text.replace('(', '').replace(')','')
            print(this_team, pl_team, kills)
```

Comment: and how could I add the different teams, furia and chaos

Comment: You mean you want to print the name of the teams before printing the data?

Comment: yes since each team has different players, want it to make it clear so I can tell which player is from which team

Comment: I edit the upper code for you, but it's not exactly the use you should do of stack overflow

Comment: I had the code for the team but I just wasnt sure how to implement with the rest of the stuff. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
stat_table = soup.find_all("table", class_="stats-table")
stat_table = stat_table[0]
```

This selects the first stats table and all the operations you perform after that operate on that table.

Instead, you could:

```
stat_tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="stats-table")
for stat_table in stat_tables:
    etc.
```